# Phase Noise(dBc/Hz) and Jitter

Tags: noise, jitter

[Jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) as wiki explains undesired deviation in the periodicity of the clock and [Phase Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_noise) is random fluctuation in the phase of waveform caused by jitter. Exploring deeper into these terms when I look at measuring units i.e. femtosec or nanosec for jitter is easy to understand about the deviation in the periodicity.

But when I look into measuring unit of phase noise it is dBc/Hz.

Please explain the insight understanding that lies in dBc/Hz and how is co-related with the jitter.

Comment: Analog Devices has a [tech note](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tutorials/MT-008.pdf) about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jitter can be thought of as phase/frequency modulation of the signal. In the frequency domain, modulation creates sidebands around the carrier. Thus, if you observe a jittered signal on a spectrum analyzer, you'll observe the carrier's frequency, and it's upper and lower sideband components of the jitter. Its important to remember that jitter occurs at different rates (frequencies). You can think of this as "how slowly or rapidly is the ideal edge position being moved from its ideal location in time". Different jitter 'frequencies' will result in frequency domain sidebands at different offset frequencies (offset from carrier frequency).

Jitter is often spec'd in the time domain. Phase noise is spec'd as the 'spot magnitude, of the sideband at a specific offset frequency.  For example, you might see a spec like -90dBc/Hz at 10kHz offset.  This says that the sideband level is 90dB down from the carrier magnitude when measured at 10kHz away from the carrier frequency, normalized to a 1Hz measurement BW.

So, you can't directly compare a dBc/Hz level with a jitter spec. The only way to relate them is to consider the complete phase noise characteristic in the frequency domain, and integrate the total amount of power in the phase noise sidebands. It is then possible to relate this total integrated phase noise power to the jitter value.

Answer (score 2):

### What is JITTER

In networks, and in particular in IP networks such as the Internet, jitter refers to the statistical variation in the delay in the reception of transmitted packets caused by internal queues of congested routers.

The "ping jittering" is the continuous variation of the packet reception delay; this problem is highlighted by the use of VoIP lines (which need a constant ping) resting on internet lines that for example have a connection to specific sectors such as WiFi cells which change according to the cell saturation. Jittering hardly occurs on HDSL lines but you have to consider the band actually used and usable.

to fix it:

1. Buy a Powerful Router
2. Use an Ethernet Cable
3. Use High-Speed Internet
4. Eliminate Jitter with Haste => 
          [HASTE](https://haste.net/2017/08/23/what-is-jitter/)
5. Or whatch this.. https://docs.cycling74.com/max5/tutorials/jit-tut/jitterchapter45.html

### Phase noise

Phase noise is measured in the frequency domain, and is expressed as a ratio of signal power to noise power
measured in a 1 Hz bandwidth at a given offset from the desired signal. A plot of responses at various offsets...
Oscillator noise performance is characterized
as jitter in the time domain and
as phase noise in the frequency domain.
Which one is preferred, time or frequency
domain, may depend on the application.
In radio frequency (RF) communications,
phase noise is preferred while in digital
systems, jitter is favored. Hence, an RF
engineer would prefer to address phase
noise while a digital engineer wants jitter
specified.
Note that phase noise and jitter are two
linked quantities associated with a noisy
oscillator and, in general, as the phase
noise increases in the oscillator, so does
the jitter.
from the desired signal is usually comprised of three distinct slopes corresponding to three primary noise
generating mechanisms in the oscillator

GOOD LUCK